# Actions must be plain objects. Redux not working

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to add redux-thunk middleware to put register and login functionality in my app. But the code doesnt seem to work for register. It is giving the following error -

**Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.**

The code is as follows

**Index.js** - Importing thunk and using it

```
 import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
 import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
 const store = createStore(authReducer,applyMiddleware(
                            thunk, 
                            loggerMiddleware
                            ),window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>, 
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

**actions/authActions.js** -Creating register function to dispatch action

```
export function register(){
    return (dispatch)=>{

        dispatch({type:'auth_user'})

    }
}
```

**components/Register.js** - Component which is using the above register function using redux

```
import  * as actions  from '../actions/authActions';

class RegisterForm extends React.Component{

handleRegister = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("inside handle register");
    console.log(this.props);
    this.props.register();
 }
}
var Register = connect(mapStateToProps,actions)(RegisterForm);
```

**authReducer.js**

```
import {AUTH_ERROR,UNAUTH_USER,FETCH_MESSAGE, AUTH_USER} from '../actions/types';


const initialState = {
    loggedIn:false,
    errorMessage:''
}

const   authReducer = (state=initialState,action)=>{
    console.log("action is")
    console.log(action);
    switch(action.type){
        case AUTH_USER:
            {
                console.log("Reached in reducer");
                return {...state,loggedIn:true}}

        case UNAUTH_USER:
            return {...state, loggedIn:false}
        default:
            return state;
    }

}

export default authReducer;
```

**/action/types.js**

```
export const AUTH_USER = 'auth_user'
export const UNAUTH_USER = 'unauth_user'
export const AUTH_ERROR = 'auth_error'
export const FETCH_MESSAGE = 'fetch_message'
```

Comment: Your store setup is wrong.

Comment: Could you please tell what is wrong. And how to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Your store setup seems incorrect. Write your store as:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  authReducer,
  {},
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(
      thunk,
      loggerMiddleware
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: Hi Arup, This is removing the error, but the action is not going into the Reducer. Could you please help with it.

Comment: @AbhishekKulshrestha Is that action doing any async call? If not, then no need to do `return (dispatch)=>{` .

Comment: In future it will do the asynchronous call, but for now I am just checking with this piece of coDe. If this works, I will put the async code inside this.

Comment: When it will be the async call, then only write it like this, until then write the actions like non async action creators..

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following snippet in the actions.

```
export function register=()=>{
    return {
        type:'auth_user'
    }
}
```